# Sql Query Json Array items by Value

Tags: json, sql-server

I have searched and can't seem to find somewhere doing exactly what I am trying.
I have a json similar to as follows in multiple rows in my database:

```
    {
    "date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "details": {
        "detail": [
            {
                "item": "11",
                "value": "xt"
            },
            {
                "item": "12",
                "value": "xy"
            },
            {
                "item": "13",
                "value": "xz"
            },
            {
                "item": "14",
                "value": "zz"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to do sql that does this:

```
select ID
       jsonColumn.value where item=11 as X
       jsonColumn.value where item=12 as Y
from tbl
```

So I have results like this

```
----------------------
|ID  |X        |Y    |
----------------------
|1   |xt       |xy   |
----------------------
```

I have tried using `JSONVALUE` but I seem to need to do it by the array item number like this:

```
  '$.details.detail[3].value'
```

which doesn't really work

I have also tried this:

```
    SELECT id, x.item, x.value
    FROM 
    tbl F
    CROSS APPLY (select *
            FROM  OPENJSON(F.Json,'$.details.detail')
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value)
                WITH (item NVARCHAR(25) '$.item',
                      value NVARCHAR(max) '$.value') As x
     where F.ID=55
```

Which I can use to print out all the items and values but then I'd have to query each separately again.

Is there a way of combining the two in to one big query that won't be completely inefficient?

Comment: So what results are you after here?

Comment: @Larnu It shows at the top - the 3rd code  formatted bit down. If it's not clear I can re-word

Comment: FYI, the JSON you have supplied is not valid.

Comment: It's sample JSON to get the general idea of what I am trying to do, but I shall edit it

Comment: It's still important it's valid, @Bex . I had to make it valid to test; which just wastes my time (and makes me think your JSON in your production environment isn't valid either, and so needs fixing).

Comment: have edited it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems what you want is a pivot. I personally use conditional aggregation over the far more restrictive `PIVOT` operator. The JSON you supplied was invalid, so I took some liberties correcting it in my sandbox environment:

```sql
SELECT --ID,
       MAX(CASE d.item WHEN 11 THEN d.[value] END) AS X,
       MAX(CASE d.item WHEN 12 THEN d.[value] END) AS Y
FROM (VALUES(@JSON))V(J) --Your Table
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.J,'$.details') 
                 WITH (detail nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON ) OJ
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.detail)
                 WITH(item int,
                      [value] nvarchar(2)) d;
```

If you are using this against a table, and not limiting the data to a single row, you'll need to also add a `GROUP BY` clause on the relevant columns (`ID`?).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what this bit is doing '(VALUES(@JSON))V(J)'  Have not seen Syntax like that? - VALUES and V(J)? Also how would you do this across multiple rows?

Comment: It's a `VALUES` table construct, @Bex . Surprised you've seen them before, they are used all the time when doing `INSERT` statements.

Comment: *"Also how would you do this across multiple rows?"* It already does.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm missing something. I have done inserts but the V(J) what's this?
Where's the part it interacts with the table as it's just passing a single JSON?

Comment: ""but the V(J) what's this?"* An Alias, @Bex. `V` for the table construct, `J` for the column. All columns and objects in a `FROM` require a name or alias, so not aliasing the construct would result in an error.

Comment: *"it's just passing a single JSON"* Because I only have a *single* example. You would be using your table, not a variable... I didn't have access to valid JSON, and I can't access your table, so i couldn't test against such a scenario. Plus your expected results only provided one row, not multiple so it was assumed you wanted only a single row result.